# In the Dark Knight, does the Joker killing his men in bank robbery make sense?

Tags: character-motivation, the-dark-knight, the-joker

He has said he is not motivated by money and proves it so why kill competent men?

EDIT: I understand the Joker does irrational things but at the same time he must function as a criminal, had significant need for money and killing competent people would not allow him to be effective and would affect his ability to recruit. So I am saying, the opening scenes rang somewhat false to me.

Comment: Because they'd obviously have no problem killing him either?  Because he can use them and outthink them?  Because he can?

Comment: @Radhil: i am guessing it is incredibly hard to recruit competent bank robbers who follow instructions.

Comment: Something about setting the world on fire just to watch it burn?

Comment: Joker did not need a reason to take an action. There is a good chance he added that up at the last minute. He does not look like a man with a plan.

Comment: Did you perhaps miss the part of the film where you learn that the Joker is insane and often does things that are highly irrational? By which I mean the entire film.

Comment: It's funny.  I mean, setting up all his partners to betray and kill each other then killing the last survivor?  I mean, it's not "joke you laugh with Batman about after paralyzing Barbara Gordon" funny but it does have a certain dark humor to it.

Comment: He's not motivated by money so hiring new dudes isn't a problem.  By the same tack, he's not motivated by efficiency, so the timesink of training new dudes isn't a problem either.

Comment: My understanding was he robbed the banks to get Gotham gangsters attention. Had he let his men keep the money per each individual then that money would have been easier to back trace rather than the one person that had a master plan to sell them on killing batman. So the madness did make sense, kill everyone that did their part of the job and keep the money to himself for his grand scheme.

Comment: Jared: I think you are right.

Comment: @Exal: No, finding people who are both competent and willing must be very hard -- there was an alarm guy and a safe cracker and these are rare scales.